# On trigger exit subctract mana

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have perform a c# script to add mana to the slider ontriggerEnter and Subtract mana on trigguerExit wen touch on Enemy object, but it seems to have some thing wrong, the script have no errors but wen its touch the Enemy Object It Take all the mana, and not the value i set.
I am new on c# scripting, tank you in advance.
This is my Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class mana : MonoBehaviour {


public void addmana()
{
    manaBar.value += 300;

}

public void Takemana()
{
    manaBar.value -= 30;

}

public Slider manaBar;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{

    manaBar.value = 300;
    if (manaBar != null)
    {
        manaBar.IsActive();
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // The switch statement checks what tag the other gameobject is, and reacts accordingly.
    switch (other.gameObject.tag)
    {
    case "manapickup":
        Debug.Log(other.gameObject.tag);
        Invoke("addmana", 0f);
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        break;

    }
    // Finally, this line destroys the gameObject the player collided with.
    //Destroy(other.gameObject);
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    // The switch statement checks what tag the other gameobject is, and reacts accordingly.
    switch (other.gameObject.tag)
    {
    case "Enemy":
        Debug.Log(other.gameObject.tag);
        Invoke("Takemana", 0f);
        break;

    }
    // Finally, this line destroys the gameObject the player collided with.
    //Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: When you touch an enemy, how many times is Debug.Log(other.tag); printing?

Comment: Also, you wrote "when touch enemy" but there is no tag for enemy in the Enter method?

Comment: well wen i touch the enemy its print once.

Comment: Tanks for the replay well i am brand new in c# and i dont know that much, can you please show me how to do.

Comment: If the provided answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the right one. _(Accepting an answer helps future visitors coming on this page)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems like the problem may come from your **Slider** component : are you sure its *maxValue* property is set to the right value ?

(by default this value is set to *1* : you can change it in the Inspector or programmatically calling `manaBar.maxValue = 1000.0f;`)

[image: Slider help maxValue]

Also I'd recommend moving the `case "Enemy": [...]` part of your script inside the `switch` of your `OnTriggerEnter` method : I see no benefit from calling it inside the `OnTriggerExit` method (but I may be wrong depending on your game's logic).

Some side notes to conclude :

- Try to keep your code organized as much as possible : one common layout is _Attributes (Properties) / Monobehaviour methods (Start, Update, OnTriggerEnter, ...) / Custom methods. This helps other when trying to solve your problems and will ease later maintenance of your code.
- Try to respect some coding standards (same as code being organized, this will vary a lot from one person/compagny to another) : in C# method names usually start with an uppercase while property names start with a lowercase.
- Finally try to stick to the "rules" you've set for yourself : here I see one of your tags is capitilized (`Enemy`) while the other isn't (`manapickup`).